# Многоуровневое меню telegram bot

Tags: python, telebot

Есть бот telegram, вот код:

```
keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(); 
key_yes = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Магазин', callback_data='shop'); 
keyboard.add(key_yes); 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "shop":
        shop = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(); 
        product = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чай Greenfield', callback_data='tea'); 
        shop.add(product);
        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
        def callback_worker(call):
            if call.data == "tea":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали чай гринфилд!');
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать !', reply_markup=shop);
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

При переходе на чай гринфилд, не срабатывает код

```
if call.data == "tea":
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали чай гринфилд!');
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Создать новый call_back для выбора (писать сall_back внутри сall_back нельзя) или:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "shop":
        shop = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(); 
        product = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чай 
         Greenfield',callback_data='tea'); 
        shop.add(product);
    elif call.data == "tea":  
         bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали чай гринфилд!');
         bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать !', 
         reply_markup=shop);
```